# Symfony 3 captcha bundle without forms

Tags: php, symfony

I need to add a simple captcha to my Symfony login form and currently I am searching for correct bundle for it. I dont need any API/ajax js support, just a bundle which generates an image on the server and then performs user input validation.

Moreover I am not using forms in my project, so I need to render an image in my `loginAction` and after that perform manual validation somewhere.

Firstly I tried `captcha.com` bundle, but as far as I understand it is not free and also it required login to `git.captcha.com` when performing `composer require ...`

After that I tried to use `Gregwar/CaptchaBundle` but its docs contain only examples with form while I need something without them. Is there any way to use `Gregwar/CaptchaBundle` without forms?

Any advice would be welcome, thank you.

Comment: Try this - the guide shows how to do this with plain PHP, you would just need to implement it the Symfony way. http://acmeextension.com/generate-captcha-image-with-php/

Keep in mind that this would be very insecure way to do this and the advice is always to use the industry standard.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `Gregwar/CaptchaBundle` like this:

```php
namespace AppBundle\Security\Captcha;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\Generator\CaptchaGenerator as BaseCaptchaGenerator;

class CaptchaGenerator
{
    /**
     * @var EngineInterface
     */
    private $templating;

    /**
     * @var BaseCaptchaGenerator
     */
    private $generator;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $sessionKey;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $options;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating, BaseCaptchaGenerator $generator, SessionInterface $session, $sessionKey, array $options)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->generator = $generator;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->sessionKey = $sessionKey;
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function generate()
    {
        $options = $this->options;
        $code = $this->generator->getCaptchaCode($options);

        $this->session->set($this->sessionKey, $options['phrase']);

        return $this->templating->render('AppBundle:My/Security:captcha.html.twig', array(
            'code' => $code,
            'width' => $options['width'],
            'height' => $options['height'],
        ));
    }
}
```

```php
namespace AppBundle\Security\Captcha;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class CaptchaValidator
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $sessionKey;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, $sessionKey)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->sessionKey = $sessionKey;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate($value)
    {
        return $this->session->get($this->sessionKey, null) === $value;
    }
}
```

```
{# AppBundle:My/Security:captcha.html.twig #}
<img class="captcha_image" src="{{ code }}" alt="" title="captcha" width="{{ width }}" height="{{ height }}" />
```

```
# services.yaml
parameters:
    app.security.captcha.security_key: captcha
services:
    AppBundle\Security\Captcha\CaptchaGenerator:
        lazy: true
        arguments:
            $sessionKey: '%app.security.captcha.security_key%'
            $options: '%gregwar_captcha.config%'

    AppBundle\Security\Captcha\CaptchaValidator:
        arguments:
            $sessionKey: '%app.security.captcha.security_key%'
```

then validate value in `AppBundle\Security\FormAuthenticator`

```php
public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
{
    if (!$this->captchaValidator->validate($token->getCaptchaValue())) {
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('security.captcha');
    }
    // ...
}
```